# when there is no data found set null

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jquery to get values from an php script and place them between  tags. But sometimes nothing is send as an value. Then i would like to show the words null.

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "rapportage/rapport_detail", 
                            data: {"klant":klant,"project":project,"van":van,"tot":tot},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(){ alert("Onvoldoende gegevens beschikbaar om rapportage to genereren."); },
                            success: function(data){ // Plaats data op de juiste plek in de tabel 
                            var titel=data.titel;
                            projectid=data.projectid;
                            console.log(projectid);
                            $.post( "rapportage/rapport_detail", { projectid: "projectid"} );
                                projecttype =data.projecttype,
                                projectleider =data.projectleider,
                                projecttype =data.projecttype,
                                statusproject =data.statusproject,
                                startproject =data.startproject,
                                deadlineproject =data.deadlineproject,
                                omzetproject =data.omzetproject,
                                kostenproject=data.kostenproject,
                                totaalurenproject =data.totaalurenproject,
                                totaalminutenproject =data.totaalminutenproject,
                                urenkostenproject =data.urenkostenproject;
         var str='';
            for(var i=0,len=titel.length;i<len;i++){
               str+="<tr>"+"<td>" + projectid[i] +  "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + titel[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + projectleider[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + projecttype[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + statusproject[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + startproject[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + deadlineproject[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + omzetproject[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + kostenproject[i] + "</td>";
               var margeproject= omzetproject[i] - kostenproject[i];
               str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + margeproject +  "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + totaalurenproject[i] + ":" + totaalminutenproject[i] + "</td>";
               str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + urenkostenproject[i] + "</td>"+"</tr>";
               }
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#table_1 tbody").append(str);
                                                    }
                                    });
```

But is this the right thing to do for an empty variable?

Comment: Depends on your requirement and how you would be using this table data. If only for displaying purpose, I would prefer to leave the `<td>` blank or not display it at all.

Comment: and add a message to the user maybe!

Answer (score 1):

it depends, if totaaluernproject is null or undefined, if it is null then there is no need to test just print the value and it will be null, other wise if it can be undefined, you can do this:

```
totaalurenproject[i] = totaalurenproject[i] || "null";
str+= "<td>" + totaalurenproject[i] + ":" + totaalurenproject[i];
```

this will give you the result in both cases with a more controlled state

Comment: This doesnt work because i just get nothing back from the totaalurenproject sometimes.

Comment: This is what i understood from your code. You want the variable to be value or null right?

Comment: Indeed that is what i want but the totaalurenproject has a value in some cases. And in some cases it doesnt has any value. And when it doesnt have any value then it needs to show null.

Comment: i cant make it work i've updated my question with the full code.